# How to put a comma in between awk when filtering columns in bash shell script?

Tags: awk

I want put a comma in between outputs from awk in bash shell script (linux).

This is a snippet of my original command

`awk {print $13, $10} >> test.csv`

If I put a comma in between `$13` and `$10`, I would get a space in between the two columns
But what I want is a comma between these two columns

I'm very new to this and I can't find any resources about this online so bear with me if this is a simple mistake. Thank you

Comment: define the output field separater (OFS) as semicolon, eg, `awk 'BEGIN {OFS=";"}{print $13,$10}'` or `awk -v OFS=";" '{print $13,$10}'`; the `OFS` takes the place of the comma between `$13` and `$10`, which would be the same as `print $13 OFS $10` (sans commas)

Comment: hi @markp-fuso, I just found out that my csv file have "separated by semicolon - ON", is that why it separates into two fields? 
is there any other way to put the semicolon(delimiter) between without modifying the csv file settings?

Comment: `tr " " ";"` will also replace any spaces in the data with semicolons; from a `bash` perspective the semicolon is just a character; if/how the character is processed depends on the program reading the data; in your case the images appear to show some sort of spreadsheet program that is treating the semicolon as a field/cell delimiter; you'll need to determine what character(s) your (spreadsheet?) program uses as delimiters and then modify the bash/awk code to generate the appropriately formatted data

Comment: If my program uses semicolon as field delimiters, how can i put semicolons in between my values without it acting as a field delimiter?

Comment: How about just `awk '{print $13 ";" $10}'`?

Comment: for a semi-colon to be treated as data you need to double-quote the entire field `awk '{print "\042" $13 ";" $10 "\042}"`

Comment: First, *don't*, even if you could. Second, you can't, *per se*, unless you are using a program to read the file that explicitly defines a method for it - in which case, that would be how. You might be able to *fake* it in some cases - for example, with HTML entities. c.f, https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+003B where you might see `&#59;` or `&#x3B;` or `&semi;` - but most programs won't see those as semicolons. Excel typically won't, for example.

Comment: @Fravadona thanks! exactly what i wanted

Comment: if your program can't distinguish between semicolons as delimiter vs data then ... can the progarm's default delimiter be changed to a character that does not show up in the data (eg, `|`); can the program accept a multi-character delimiter (eg, `&&%%`)? can you manually enter your data (including semicolon) into the program and then save to a file ... then look at the file to see how the program denotes a semicolon as delimiter vs data ... you could then use this knowledge to modify your awk script to generate the same format

Answer (score 2):

#### suggestion 1

```
  awk '{print $13 ";" $10}' >> CPU2.csv
```

#### suggestion 2

```
  awk '{print $13, $10}' OFS=";" >> CPU2.csv
```

#### suggestion 3

```
 awk '{printf("%s;%s\n", $13, $10)}' >> CPU2.csv
```

Comment: Also `awk -v OFS=';' '{print $13, $10}'`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, same is suggestion #2

Comment: Same effect, different style. Worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "1 2 3"|awk '{a=";";print $1a$2","$3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

not as elegant as I hoped, but this should work :

```
mawk 'NF=($+_=$13(_)$10)~_' \_=\;
```

It first overwrites the entire row with just `$13` and `$10`, with the semi-colon `;` in between. `_` is a semi-colon, thus numerical evaluation of `$+_` is identical to `$0`, and since I've forced the delimiter in between them, the regex test of presence of semi-colon will always yield `true` (`1`), making `NF = 1`, and printing just that.

Assigning `1` into `NF` in lieu of `$1 = $1`.

`NF` isn't a 2 because I'm using the new sep in between them, instead of space or tab, so even though `$0` was overwritten, `awk` wouldn't have found the sep it needed to split out 2nd field.

Tested on `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.9.9.6`, `macOS nawk`, and `gawk 5.1.1`, including `gawk -t` traditional flag and `gawk -P` posix mode.

-- `The 4Chan Teller`